# sending email to all newsletter members with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, newsletter

I want to send an email using `codeigniter` library to my newsletter members and I want to mention each members' Email address in email's content. For doing that, I used `foreach loop` to send the email one by one. **The problem is that the code sends email to just one member ( the first member ) of my newsletter.** I've checked my code which gets members from the database and it printed out all the members.

This is my model:

```
function send_news()
{
    $subscribers = $this->get_subscriber_data();
    foreach($subscribers as $subscriber)
    {
        $this->load->helper('typography');

        //Format email content using an HTML file
        $data['news_Title'] = $this->input->post('news_Title');
        $HTML_Message = $this->load->view('admin/includes/newsletter_html_format', $data, true);

        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('newsletter@site.com', 'newsletter of site.com');
        $this->email->to($subscriber->subscriber_Email);
        $this->email->subject('newsletter of site.com');
        $this->email->message($HTML_Message);

        return $this->email->send();
    }

}
```

and this is how I'm getting subscribers list:

```
function get_subscriber_data($options = array())
{
    $query = $this->db->get('mg_newsletter');

    if(isset($options['subscriber_Id']))
        return $query->row(0);

    return $query->result();
}
```

when I try to echo `$subscriber->subscriber_Email` it prints all the emails in the database one after another. but it does not send email to all of them. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: note: using `BCC` would be better in your case

Comment: but as I said, I mention the subscribers Email inside HTML file. and it requires of using foreach loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "return" -ing inside your loop, which exits the function.

Just send

Comment: it's because I'm getting the return in a controller to set flashdata whether the action was successful or not. am I doing it wrong?!

Comment: yes. When you say "return", you exit the function. You will want to do a check in each loop, for example, and exit the first time it fails, or else OUTSIDE the loop return a "true" that it passed

Comment: Thanks. it helped me out. but, would you please edit your answer and have an example that how I'm going to return true or false when is fails or else?!

Comment: just use a conditional, mate. basic "if !" for failing

Comment: inside the loop or outside that?!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
 $this->email->clear()
```

As codeignitor says:
Initializes all the email variables to an empty state. This function is intended for use if you run the email sending function in a loop, permitting the data to be reset between cycles.

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

If you set the parameter to TRUE any attachments will be cleared as well. Then let us know

Comment: Yes, I forgot to use `$this->email->clear()` . but it's not what I need. because the problem still remains.

Comment: It sends the last email or the first one? and have you checked that weather your properity even returns an array?

Comment: I send just one email. This email is being sent to one of my newsletter members which is the first member that have subscribed to the newsletter. For example, I've got 13 members, and the message is being sent to the user with the ID number of "1"

Comment: Regarding the return, you can use 

 if ( ! $this->email->send())
{
    // Generate error
}

its suggest by CI instead of using return

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the loading helper file and email configuration outside the loop and then remove the return from for loop, it will send to all subscribers one by one and then after loop finishes you can do the return statement.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.